# Is it possible to detect from the power outlet if there would be current that needs grounding?

Tags: electrical, grounding

In my house we have 2 outlet power sockets (no earth) and whenever I charge my laptop I would get electric shock from the laptop when I am touching ground like if I hold laptop on my lap and touch the wall or if my foot touches the floor. At the very least I feel vibrations in the laptop. Same for CPU body, mobile (if has some metal layer on it) ..

I have solved this problem for my room only by grounding my extension where I plug charger to garden outside my room. Basically my extention sockets have 3 outlets, I plugged one end of a cooper cable in one of the grounding outlet and the other in the garden soil.
This solved the problem for my room, I do'nt get any vibration or current shock from my laptop in my room.

The problem persists though in the rest of sockets in our house like if I charge my htc desire mobile which has a bit of metal on it, I would be shocked if I happen to touch it bare footed while it is charging..

So this situation is persistent now and not something that happens rarely or occasionally.

I have tested the 2 outlets of the power socket

- I have checked the neutral/cold line shows no current (using the current testing screw driver), so assuming the potential is 0 there,
- hot line indicated current as expected
- The wire that I used in my room to ground one of the sockets, shows a bit of current

So given my situation that I have 2 pin power socks and house is not wired with grounding/earthing wire, how can I find the cause and resolve it

Comment: Short answer: If you replace your circuit breaker with a GFCI type, or replace your outlet with a GFCI outlet, it will detect that current from the hot line is not returning through the neutral and shut down the circuit before you electrocute yourself. As to how to fix this so that not only do you stay alive, but also be able to use the outlet for something useful, I think we need more information. It's not obvious to me from what you've said where the real problem is. Do you ever get shocked by lamps or other appliances in your house?

Comment: "get an electric shock from the laptop when I am touching ground" - please expand on what you mean by "touching ground"?  Are you touching the ground beneath your feet?  Or are you touching the ground plug on the laptop power cord?

Comment: Most computer power bricks don't have a ground so not sure that would help you in your case. FWIW, the old Apple TiBooks had this issue where you could feel current with your palms on the computer and bare feet on concrete or earth. I solved it by always having my feet on a rubber matt.

Comment: photon's is not correct that is just a placebo method.  da01 plenty of the larger laptops are 3 prong.  130w power supplies tend to have 3 prongs.  original post is unclear are there 2 prongs at the wall or 3?  if 3 who ever wired your house if a professional should repair the miss wiring though it may have been done before code required such. you need 3 wires from the pannel to the 3 prong outlets even with 2 prongs you should not be getting shocked there may be a large number of issues with the system.

Comment: @Kendrick In the wall each socket has 2 holes - My laptop charger has 3 pin plug, I use 3 to 2 adapter to plug it into wall

Comment: Ground(earth) is a safety device, and should **never** have current on it (under normal circumstances). If a device is shocking you, adding a ground is **not** the way to solve the problem.  Either the device is faulty (contains a ground fault, which energizes the frame/case), or the building wiring is faulty. Either way the solution is not adding a ground, it is to locate and fix the fault.

Comment: Is it possible there is stray current in the ground which is shocking you?

Comment: @Tester101 Its not just the case with one device, several devices are behaving same. Today I discovered the washing machine is giving slight current too. So how do I begin the process of locating the fault and fixing it, if grounding is not the solution ?

Comment: @Ahmed The best option would be to contact an Electrician.  Even with the proper knowledge and tools, it can be very difficult to locate wiring faults. It's too difficult to troubleshoot through the internet, and would take far more than a short answer on this site to teach you how to do it yourself.

Comment: @Tester101 Thanks, I appreciate your help, a lot of things which were unclear to me earlier are now understood from discussion, I would consult an electrician to resolve it thanks once again

Comment: unfortunatly it is a common issue and can get quite serious.  APC makes big bucks off of selling electrical audits to find these kinds of faults in businesses. wiring faults like that are likely to cause fires etc so the sooner the better.  most of my house needed to be rewired when we moved in.  they have things reversed at the wall some how the pannel was proper and the black wire went to the proper terminal on the outlets but the polarity was reversed its been quite a perplexing mess.

Answer (score 2):

I'd pick up one of these at the hardware store:

[image]

If you're not in North America, I'm sure there's a local equivalent.
Based on the LED's that light up, you can tell if the circuit is wired correctly.  The only thing it can't detect is a ground/neutral swap.  But it can detect a missing ground.

Comment: He mentioned a lack of earth (ground), so I'm not sure this tester will identify much in that situation, other than "no ground".

Comment: @Chris Cudmore There is no earth wired in the house all power sockets in the wall have 2 holes ..

Comment: 3-prong tester won't be much help with 2-prong receptacles. :)

Answer (score 1):

That you're using a two-prong outlet is a red herring. Your laptop's charger is not a three-prong device, right? If you plugged it into a properly wired and grounded three-prong outlet, the situation would be the same. The third prong actually has to be *used* to have any benefit at all.

This business of being shocked by the laptop is a consequence of its bad design. Internally it has a "ground-like" network that we might call "common". Although it has no real ground, it has a connection between its "common" and the chassis.  (A grounded chassis **is** a good idea---*if* there is a real ground.)

This common is "floating" with respect to some actual ground (meaning that it's at a different voltage), and so if you get yourself in between this common and a ground, electricity wants to go through you.

According to Dell, the shocks are harmless: http://www.pcworld.com/article/141516/article.html  :)

Also: your screwdriver is not a current tester. It detects the presence of voltage. It works by making you part of a circuit. (Recall, we know from Dell above that using people as resistors and capacitors is completely harmless!)  If you touch something that is above or below ground potential, then you complete a circuit. A tiny current flows through test light, you, to the ground, enough to light the test light.

According to your test, there isn't enough voltage across your body when you touch neutral. So your room is at the same potential. The ground wire from the garden is at a different potential, so it lights up the screwdriver. This does not prove or disprove whether that line is a proper ground. A proper electrical ground is not only a voltage reference level, but a sink that can take large amounts of current (not only the tiny current that lights up the screwdriver). So the wire has to be thick gauge. And you have to have a good coupling to the soil (like a long metal rod that is deeply pounded into the soil). The soil must not be very resistive, either.

I would contact your city for advice. Other houses in the neighborhood surely have the same kind of old wiring.  Running ad hoc wires into garden soil is probably not the way.